# Protocol 'xxx' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I want to create a custom `UITableView`, with custom delegate/dataSource methods. I would also like to pass the type of the data source when doing so. Here is what I tried:

```
struct TestModel {
    var name: String
}

protocol TestTableViewDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {    
    associatedtype CellModel        
    func cell(model: CellModel, path: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell        
}

class TestTableView: UITableView {        
    var testDelegate: TestTableViewDelegate?        
}

class VCTest: UIViewController, TestTableViewDelegate {       

    typealias CellModel = TestModel    
    var t: TestTableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        t.testDelegate = self
    }

    func cell(model: TestModel, path: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error at the `testDelegate` declaration line:

> Protocol 'TestTableViewDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

I don't really understand what's going on here. What does this mean and how could I solve it?

Thank your for your help.

Comment: See https://robnapier.net/start-with-a-protocol

Comment: About the error in general. See [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-fix-the-error-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associated-type-requirements) then see [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/why-associated-type-requirements-become-generic-constraints/). Last but not least, try writing `var x: Equatable?`; `var y: Equatable?` Would you expect `if x == y {}` to compile?

Comment: Thank you @Alexander and Honey for these great lectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the swift generic and easy way to do this is to remove the Associate type.

```
protocol TestTableViewDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {
    func cell<T>(model: T, path: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
}

class TestTableView: UITableView {
    var testDelegate: TestTableViewDelegate?
}

class VCTest: UIViewController, TestTableViewDelegate {

    func cell<TestModel>(model: TestModel, path: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    var t: TestTableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        t.testDelegate = self
    }
}
```

Another way to test (Not sure about the result):

```
class TestTableView<TestTableViewDelegate>: UITableView {
    var testDelegate: TestTableViewDelegate?
}

class VCTest: UIViewController, TestTableViewDelegate {

    typealias CellModel = TestModel
    var t: TestTableView<Any>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        t.testDelegate = self
    }

    func cell(model: TestModel, path: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}
```